FF4J web console does not render correctly and does not flip manually the feature
I am trying to adopt FF4J into my Spring Boot 3.2.5 Java application. I just want to make a simple example work in which I flip features only in the web console (by the way, what strategy is that). Below is my code and besides the rendering issue, the flip does not do anything as the app continues to see only the default value of the "enable" flag.
Maven pom.xml, had to exclude the FF4J springdoc due to clashes with my own
<!-- Feature toggling -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
      <version>3.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.ff4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>ff4j-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
      <version>1.9</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
          <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.ff4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>ff4j-web</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

package feature_toggle;

import org.ff4j.FF4j;
import org.ff4j.core.Feature;
import org.ff4j.strategy.time.ReleaseDateFlipStrategy;
import org.ff4j.web.FF4jDispatcherServlet;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingBean;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class Ff4jConfig {

    public static final String HELLO_EXAMPLE_FEATURE = "HELLO_EXAMPLE_FEATURE";

    @Bean
    public FF4j ff4j(){
        FF4j ff4j = new FF4j();

        var feature = new Feature(HELLO_EXAMPLE_FEATURE);
        feature.setEnable(false);
        feature.setFlippingStrategy(new ReleaseDateFlipStrategy("2024-06-20-20:00"));

        ff4j.createFeature(feature);
        return ff4j;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public FF4jDispatcherServlet ff4jDispatcherServlet(FF4j ff4j){
        FF4jDispatcherServlet ff4jDispatcherServlet = new FF4jDispatcherServlet();
        ff4jDispatcherServlet.setFf4j(ff4j);
        return ff4jDispatcherServlet;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean(FF4jDispatcherServlet ff4jDispatcherServlet){
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(ff4jDispatcherServlet, "/ff4j-web-console/*");
    }
}


@Service
public class FF4JService {

    @Autowired
    private FF4j ff4j;

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner commandLineRunner(){
        return args -> {
            while(true){
                if(ff4j.check(Ff4jConfig.HELLO_EXAMPLE_FEATURE)){
                    System.out.println("Hello World!");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Something went wrong!");
                }
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }
        };
    }

}


How it renders


For starters stop mixing versions, and if there is a starter I doubt you need configuration.

Use version 2.1, the versions you included are for older Spring and Spring Boot versions. And use the ff4j-spring-boot-starter-webmvc dependency.
